# How is time distrubuted as part of NITZ

Tags: gsm

I am trying to understand the time distribution in GSM using the NITZ (Network Identify and Time Zone). Is there any documentation around this feature? I am trying to find which component (HLR,MSC,BSS etc) is involved in the time distribution before the Android phone can use the time from the network.